# git не распознает перемещение с редактированием файла

Tags: git

Иногда, при перемещении и редактировании файла, `git` не распознает это и оформляет при коммите как удаление файла и добавление нового другого. Можно ли ему как-то подсказать, что это один файл?

Comment: Нельзя. git вообще не следит за перемещениями.  То что он их иногда показывает основано исключительно на «похожести» файлов. Так что если файл сильно поменялся, то git не может угадать что это было перемещение.

Comment: Хотя при выводе можно попросить его «повнимательнее» искать возможные переименования. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt--Mltngt https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Mltngt

Comment: Все правильно, гит так и работает, на удалениях и созданиях. Нечего волноваться, все нормально.